# Error while uploading base64 image to server

Tags: swift

When I manually add base64 image in php script, everything is fine, but when I send it with httpBody, all fields work and base64 String is empty on server.
Swift code:

```
    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: UrlConstant.InsertItem)!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "image\(item.imageBase64!)&cityName=\(item.cityName)&shopName=\(item.shopName)&price=\(item.price)&dateExpiring=\(item.dateExpiring)&category=\(item.category)&location=\(item.locationCoords)&u_username=\(item.u_username)&u_id=\(item.u_id)"


    urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void  in

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                do{
                   print("status code ok")
                }catch{
                   print("ERROR")
                }
            }

        }else{
            print("server not active")
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    }
```

Part of code in PHP where I get those values:

```
$cityName = $_POST['cityName'];
$shopName = $_POST['shopName'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$dateExpiring = $_POST['dateExpiring'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$u_username = $_POST['u_username'];
$u_id = $_POST['u_id'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
```

And then I process it... All fields work except $image (base64 string).

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
let postString = "image\(item.imageBase64!)&cityName=\(item.cityName)&shopName=\(item.shopName)&price=\(item.price)&dateExpiring=\(item.dateExpiring)&category=\(item.category)&location=\(item.locationCoords)&u_username=\(item.u_username)&u_id=\(item.u_id)"
```

is missing the first `=` right after "image".